# Using maven-release-plugin wit Git

Tags: git, version-control, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have created a java project with maven. I am trying to make releases of my project using maven-release plugin.

when i execute following commands in the order shown in the image below, maven release plugin stuck where it tries to push the changes to git repository

Could anybody help me to figure out the issue here.

[image]

I have added SCM section into the project object model of my application. I also have set the passphrase using ssh-add. but still no luck :(

this is the new error i am getting after applying the change to the scm section

[image]

Comment: can you copy and past that error message?

Comment: no error message. it is just hanging there and no progress at all

Answer (score 1):

Your log shows that Maven is trying to push using HTTPS. You may have not configured HTTP(S) authentication, that's why pushing to remote repository fails.

Since you want to use SSH, you must change your `<developerConnection>` tag to `scm:git:ssh://git@github.com:kitis/sample-multimodule-project.git`.

If you want to use HTTP(S) for pushing, you may try to use a `.netrc` file.

Comment: I did the modification as you explained, but still no luck :(

Comment: I've updated my post with an `ssh://` part in the URL. My fault, I didn't double check my answer.

Comment: I am getting new error message now, it says 

ssh: github.com:kitis: no address associated with name

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird. The following projects are using maven-release and github, you can check their `<scm>` config to see if it works for you : https://github.com/excilys/gatling/blob/master/pom.xml / https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/pom.xml .

Answer (score 1):

Issue for first image, it may be caused due to missing scm credentials.
I used maven 3.0.5, m2releaseplugin 2.3.2 and git as scm.
This problem can be solved by providing scm parameters "username" and "password" on project's pom.xml. Check scm plugin parameters from maven help.
If you are using Jenkins CI and m2 release plugin, you can specify username/password parameters from web gui.
This is due to scm plugin dependency of release plugin.
Hope this helps